# Android application optimal design with several activities

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, uart

I'm developing a quite big app with several activities, [see link](http://maxbodyshape.se/ezy_design.png), and I have 2 questions about the base design.

1. What is best practise concerning opening activities, so that that i don't waste memory by having multiple instances of the same class open at same time and such?
2. The app must receive USB-data constantly through a UART-interface, and should somehow forward this data to the activity in focus. For now the start activity receive the data through a handler. this would work if only one activity needed the USB-data. How should I do this?

**Start.java**

```
final Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override 
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        if(actualNumBytes[0] != 0x00)
        {
            info.append(String.copyValueOf(readBuffer, 0, actualNumBytes[0]));
        }
    }
};
```

**handler_thread.java**

```
/*usb input data handler*/
private class handler_thread extends Thread 
{
    Handler mHandler;

    handler_thread(Handler h ){
        mHandler = h;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } 
            catch(InterruptedException e){}

            status = uartInterface.ReadData((byte)64, readBuffer, actualNumBytes);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you wish to minimize the number of activities, consider using fragments instead.
2. If you have a global variable/event/thread that need to be handled by the current activity, put it in a service, and let the activity communicate with it (connect on start/resume, disconnect on pause/stop).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Have'nt worked with fragments or services before, but i will read into it!

Comment: Yes, and if you need the variable/thread to live as long as possible, even if the user has left the app, you can set the service to run in the foreground (and use a notification for this).

Also, in general, each time you find an answer to fit your needs and you think it has answered your question, you tick it (click the "V" button) as "answered".

Comment: I will mark as answeard as soon as i get it to work :) Thanks!